# Would I violate copyright by making transcriptions of copyrighted music and posting them online if I don't make money off of it?

Tags: fair-use, music

If I were to make transcriptions of copyrighted music and make them available on sites such as MuseScore or post the audio on YouTube and I did not make any kind of advertising revenue or any money selling the transcriptions, would I face any kinds of legal problems?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would probably result in a copyright violation. You're making a copy of the work, albeit in a different medium.

The fact that you make no money wouldn't do much to help you. The question is not really whether you're making money, but rather whether you're cutting into the artist's ability to make money. Giving away copies for free is a pretty good way to do that.

Comment: Yes it's allowed or yes you'll run into trouble?

Comment: Yes, that conduct could result in legal problems.

Comment: Websites publishing unauthorized third-party copyright infringements are not automatically exempt from criminal prosecution or civil damages for assisting in the unlawful acts of those third parties who have posted those works.